# UML Class Diagram: How do I omit attribute compartment AND omit parameters in operation compartment?

Tags: uml

I want to draw a UML class in which the only thing I specify is the names of operations. In other words there is no attribute compartment, and the method compartment contains names of methods, but no parameters. I have read the UML reference guide, and apparently I am allowed to do something like this

```
--------------
|    Car      |
--------------
|changeChassis|
--------------
```

Where Car is the class name, and changeChassis is a method that takes parameters whose types I do not want to specify. In other words, a Java implementation of the above class might be

```
public class Car {
     private String chassis;
     public void changeChassis(String chassis) {
          this.chassis=chassis;
}
```

The snag is that my diagram is ambiguous. I've omitted the attribute compartment, but without a parameter list, my method changeChassis could be an attribute.

Some texts I have read suggest that you can use an empty parameter list to indicate an operation, even if the operation actually does take parameters. For example you could write changeChassis() even if the operation you were referring to actually was meant to take a parameter. However the UML reference does not allow this, and it's obviously ambiguous.

Another solution would be to just put in an empty attribute compartment. For example:

```
--------------
|    Car      |
--------------
|             |
--------------
|changeChassis|
--------------
```

However the UML reference says you can't do that unless the class genuinely has no attributes.

Is there any way of doing what I want that abides by the standard, and avoids ambiguity?

Answer (score 2):

NO this is a very bad practice, at the first your demo doesn't have any method, in fact the developer find the `changeChassis` as an attribute, this is possible that omit the return type of void method, or omit the name of input arguments, but this is not recommended.
you need to specify the whole class structure.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [UML specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/), you have to represent the operation with its name of course, parameters and brakets.
If you omits parameters, but keeping empty brakets, it will have ambiguities with other possible operations having same name but not the same parameters..
If you omits parameters and brakets, it will have ambiguities with other possible operations having the same name but not the same parameters but also with attributes...